# z-index not working when trying to set an element as a background

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

As the title says, I'm trying to set particle js as a background for my hero section. I've looked through many forums and always see the same solution in CSS:

```
 position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
```

However, adding the same CSS to my project doesn't work as expected. Every time I use z-index: -1; it disappears. I've even tried position: fixed; position: relative; and to no avail.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to my source code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mejiabrayan/pen/NWYooJR)

Comment: Is there another element with a z-index of -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `#bg` element is work properly and it is on the back of your `main` section.

but there is another element `.bg-dark` which has non-transparent background-color on top layer of `#bg` which you see that.

you can simply remove `bg-dark` class from all container `div` inside of `main` like these :

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzGlH.png) ,
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXbWp.png)